# Can't build any projects with Visual Studio 2022/2019

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Every time I try to build any project, I get `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

I tried:

- Reinstalling VS 2022
- Reinstalling VS 2019
- Repairing VS
- Updating Windows
- Disabling and removing antivirus software as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305318/visual-studio-2022-cant-build-any-projects)
- Cleaning various temp and cache folders as suggested [here](https://errorhandlinginskills.wordpress.com/2018/07/28/how-to-clear-visual-studio-cache/)

Here is some interesting parts of build output with verbosity set to "detailed" (or [full output here](https://pastebin.com/mutkEa4K))

```
1>Target CoreCompile:
1>  Building target "CoreCompile" completely.
1>  Output file "obj\Debug\net6.0\ClassLibrary1.dll" does not exist.
1>  Using "Csc" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll".
1>  Task "Csc"
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702,2008 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:6 /define:TRACE;DEBUG;NET;NET6_0;NETCOREAPP;NET5_0_OR_GREATER;NET6_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\netstandard.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.AppContext.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Buffers.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.Specialized.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Console.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Data.Common.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Formats.Asn1.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Globalization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Pipes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Memory.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.HttpListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Mail.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.NameResolution.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Ping.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Requests.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Sockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebClient.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebProxy.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebSockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ObjectModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Emit.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Resources.Reader.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Resources.Writer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Handles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Loader.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Claims.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Principal.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Security.SecureString.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ServiceProcess.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Channels.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Thread.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Timer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Transactions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Transactions.Local.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.ValueTuple.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XPath.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\ref\net6.0\WindowsBase.dll" /debug+ /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\net6.0\ClassLibrary1.dll /refout:obj\Debug\net6.0\refint\ClassLibrary1.dll /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:10.0 /analyzerconfig:obj\Debug\net6.0\ClassLibrary1.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig /analyzerconfig:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\analyzers\build\config\analysislevel_6_default.editorconfig" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.3\analyzers/dotnet/cs/System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll" Class1.cs "obj\Debug\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\net6.0\ClassLibrary1.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605
1>    CompilerServer: server failed - server rejected the request due to analyzer / generator issues 'Unable to get nested type properties.' - 7e3f0a7d-473e-4c39-acc4-63e7b964cca0
1>    Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.1.0-5.22109.6 (0c82c411)
1>    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1>
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error : Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unable to get nested type properties.
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader..ctor(Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options, Int32 size)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ModuleMetadata.CreateFromStream(Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Stream peStream, String path, MetadataReferenceProperties properties, DocumentationProvider documentation)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler.<GetMetadataProvider>b__47_0(String path, MetadataReferenceProperties properties)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler.LoggingMetadataFileReferenceResolver.ResolveReference(String reference, String baseFilePath, MetadataReferenceProperties properties)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLineArguments.ResolveMetadataReference(CommandLineReference cmdReference, MetadataReferenceResolver metadataResolver, List`1 diagnosticsOpt, CommonMessageProvider messageProviderOpt)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLineArguments.ResolveMetadataReferences(MetadataReferenceResolver metadataResolver, List`1 diagnosticsOpt, CommonMessageProvider messageProviderOpt, List`1 resolved)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler.ResolveMetadataReferences(List`1 diagnostics, TouchedFileLogger touchedFiles, MetadataReferenceResolver& referenceDirectiveResolver)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompiler.CreateCompilation(TextWriter consoleOutput, TouchedFileLogger touchedFilesLogger, ErrorLogger errorLogger, ImmutableArray`1 analyzerConfigOptions, AnalyzerConfigOptionsResult globalConfigOptions)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler.RunCore(TextWriter consoleOutput, ErrorLogger errorLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler.Run(TextWriter consoleOutput, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Csc.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Run>b__0(TextWriter tw)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.ConsoleUtil.RunWithUtf8Output[T](Func`2 func)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Csc.Run(String[] args, BuildPaths buildPaths, TextWriter textWriter, IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader analyzerLoader)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.BuildClient.RunLocalCompilation(String[] arguments, BuildPaths buildPaths, TextWriter textWriter)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.BuildClient.RunCompilation(IEnumerable`1 originalArguments, BuildPaths buildPaths, TextWriter textWriter, String pipeName)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.BuildClient.Run(IEnumerable`1 arguments, RequestLanguage language, CompileFunc compileFunc, CompileOnServerFunc compileOnServerFunc)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String[] args)
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.Main(String[] args)
1>  Done executing task "Csc" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "ClassLibrary1.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Target _CheckForCompileOutputs:
1>Target "_SGenCheckForOutputs" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)' == 'On' or ('@(WebReferenceUrl)'!='' and '$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)' == 'Auto')) was evaluated as ('Off' == 'On' or (''!='' and 'Off' == 'Auto')).
1>Target _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites:
1>  Using "ReadLinesFromFile" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>  Task "ReadLinesFromFile"
1>  Done executing task "ReadLinesFromFile".
1>  Using "ConvertToAbsolutePath" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>  Task "ConvertToAbsolutePath"
1>  Done executing task "ConvertToAbsolutePath".
1>  Using "FindUnderPath" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>  Task "FindUnderPath"
1>    Comparison path is "M:\bybis\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1".
1>  Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
1>  Task "FindUnderPath"
1>    Comparison path is "bin\Debug\net6.0\".
1>  Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
1>  Task "FindUnderPath"
1>    Comparison path is "obj\Debug\net6.0\".
1>  Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
1>  Using "RemoveDuplicates" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>  Task "RemoveDuplicates"
1>  Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
1>Target _CleanRecordFileWrites:
1>  Task "RemoveDuplicates"
1>  Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
1>  Task "MakeDir"
1>  Done executing task "MakeDir".
1>  Task "WriteLinesToFile"
1>  Done executing task "WriteLinesToFile".
1>
1>Done building project "ClassLibrary1.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
```

Error in VS
[image: Error in VS22]

Error in Event Viewer
[image: Error in event viewer]

Comment: Definitely a machine-specific configuration problem. Per the Event Viewer, the C# compiler is failing (`Roslyn\csc.exe`). So, it is not a Visual Studio problem *per se*. Looks like you've tried all of the standard fixes. If it were me, my next step would be to wipe and rebuild the machine. Too much troubleshooting is not worth it. Your mileage may vary, though.

Comment: Interestingly, "dotnet build" builds same empty project just fine. Rebuilding this specific machine would be very very painful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74811732/90475